# Maven plugin to generate an executable web application (war->executable jar-war)

Tags: maven, web-applications, jetty, war, executable-jar

I have a maven project that is generating a .war file.

I want to configure maven to generate an executable jar, that embeds a servlet container (jetty, tomcat, or others) plus my war application, and generate an executable jar that can run my web application with a command like:

```
java -jar mywebapp.war
```

Is there a maven plugin to obtain such artifact?

At the moment I'm using [jetty-runner](http://webtide.intalio.com/2008/04/jetty-runner/) to run a test version of my app, it's quite satisfying for test, but not as as handy for redistribution as it would be an executable war (like in jenkins).

#### Update

@jesse-mcconnell: I don't want to change a single line in my web application (except in the pom.xml) to achieve the result. It's just a matter to package my war differently, and keep it deployable under an appserver of choice, plus having the ability to run it as an executable war.

A perfect solution should also give me the ability to choose which appserver to embed, also specifying all needed configuration files contained in the executable war itself.

@khmarbaise: I know about jenkins, I already checked the code long time back, it uses winstone  servlet container, and it puts a Main.class in the war which is accessible from http (and I think it's wrong)

A perfect solution could generate a war containing stuff like this:

```
├── META-INF 
│   └── MANIFEST.MF (Main-Class: WEB-INF.container.classes.Main)
└── WEB-INF
    ├── web.xml
    ├── classes
    ├── lib
    └── container
        ├── lib (jetty.jar/tomcat.jar/whatever.jar)
        ├── etc (configuration files for the container)
        └── classes
            └── Main.class
```

1. Main.class should use etc configuration as default, but being able to override common parameters at the command line (port, context,etc) or specifying a new configuration.
2. Main.class should be able to load the container jar and configuration from inside the container (or extract into tmp.dir) and start up the appserver.

This is how I would make it.

At the end, you have a normal war, that can be deployed in any appserver, with the ability to run in a self-contained way.

Comment: in that case you will need a custom impl that will handle all the classloader issues that this approach entails...perhaps an extension to ClassWorlds or something, fwiw nothing comes to mind in an out of the box implementation like this

Comment: That would be what I consider a definitive solution to the problem. But, also an imperfect (but working) solution would be welcome.
BTW, I'm looking in some code right now, I hope the classloading issues won't be so hard to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat Maven plugin do that have a look here http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/executable-war-jar.html

HTH

Comment: checked; it's kind of ok. It generates a jar that contains the war, then extracts it at runtime. I think, I'll end up doing the mojo, my way.

Answer (score 3):

Use the maven jar plugin to set the Main-Class in the manifest, and then write a main method with something akin to this (or that calls into code like this):

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneServletContext.java?h=jetty-8

You can register your servlets and wire up the webapp accordingly.

The issue with bundling a war file proper inside of a jar file is that you would need a specialized deployer that understands deploying a war file from within a jar, not a common thing.  So creating an uber type jar is probably the better way to go.  Besides, one of the big reasons of the actual WebAppContext is the classloader isolation which is kinda moot in these cases.

You can use the maven-dependency-plugin to unpack the various dependencies you need.  There are other plugins you can use like the maven-uberjar-plugin (I think that was the name) but you can do it simply with the maven-dependency-plugin + a custom main class akin to something like the above.

I like this approach as you end up with a main method that you can run in eclipse that starts up the whole application and lets you debug the whole thing as well, often quite a win.

Edit: for posterity, jetty also releases with an artifact called jetty-runner that allows for running war files directly off of the command line

Answer (score 2):

No that i know but check the [jenkins source code which supports](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/war/pom.xml) starting directly from command like you expected to work.

Comment: If it doesn't exists I'll make it